# Convert Signature Bitmap to Signature String (very strange one)

Tags: vb.net, image, graphics, bitmap

Basically I need to convert a bitmap image into a string but it is not a common one.

The dilemma is that this string is composed of two parts:

1) Points
2) Lines

I need to convert the image into two parts delimited by a *.

One example I have been given is:

```
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
```

so all I know is that the 221A is the points and the other string is lines but need to be able to achieve that.

Have nay of you come across this before ?

I have tried converting the bitmap to Base64String but that doesn't give my anything near.

If it Helps I only have the reverse in VB i.e. from string to image:

```
Private Sub unpackBMP(ByVal BITMAP As String)
Dim points As String
Dim lines As String
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim x1 As Long
Dim y1 As Long

points = firstItem(BITMAP, "*")
lines = BITMAP


While Len(points) > 0

x = "&H" & Mid(points, 1, 2)
y = "&H" & Mid(points, 3, 2)
points = Mid(points, 5, Len(points) - 4)

'picDraw.PSet (Val(x), Val(y)), vbBlack
'Call picDraw.DrawPoint(CDbl(x), CDbl(y))
'picDraw.Refresh
Wend


While Len(lines) > 0

x = "&H" & Mid(lines, 1, 2)
y = "&H" & Mid(lines, 3, 2)
x1 = "&H" & Mid(lines, 5, 2)
y1 = "&H" & Mid(lines, 7, 2)

lines = Mid(lines, 9, Len(lines) - 8)

'picDraw.Line (Val(x), Val(y))-(Val(x1), Val(y1)), vbBlack
'Call picDraw.DrawLine(CDbl(x), CDbl(y), CDbl(x1), CDbl(y1), 0)
'picDraw.Refresh
Wend

'Call picDraw.DrawLine(lines(1, tmp), lines(2, tmp), lines(3, tmp), lines(4, tmp), 0)
End Sub

Public Function firstItem(pstrItems As String, pstrDelim As String) As String

Dim lngPos As Long
Dim strRes As String
'Dim strDelim As String

strRes = ""

lngPos = InStr(pstrItems, pstrDelim)

If lngPos > 0 Then
  strRes = Left$(pstrItems, lngPos - 1)
  pstrItems = Mid$(pstrItems, lngPos + 1)
Else
  strRes = pstrItems
  pstrItems = ""
End If

firstItem = strRes

End Function
```

Let me know if you require any further details.

Background: This is a signature in a picture box on a windows mobile 6.5 device. Please see below for the image and its related string. Hopefully this helps.

[image: 280172 - Signature bmp]

```
String for SIGNATURE 280172:
3711*371127152715103510351F2C1F2C312231223C1C3C1C3D203D20352D352D333233323D2E3D2E52225222671A671A6C196C196D1A6D1A6D1D6D1D69226922652665266428642864296429652965296E236E23781E781E8718871891179117961896189A199A199B1B9B1B9D1E9D1E9F209F20A021A021A021
```

Adding the attachment stack makes it a png but it is a bmp file, however it is a 204 x 64 1 bit depth image.

Reordered string (by Spektre)

```
3711*3711
2715 2715
1035 1035
1F2C 1F2C
3122 3122
3C1C 3C1C
3D20 3D20
352D 352D
3332 3332
3D2E 3D2E
5222 5222
671A 671A
6C19 6C19
6D1A 6D1A
6D1D 6D1D
6922 6922
6526 6526
6428 6428
6429 6429
6529 6529
6E23 6E23
781E 781E
8718 8718
9117 9117
9618 9618
9A19 9A19
9B1B 9B1B
9D1E 9D1E
9F20 9F20
A021 A021 A021
```

Single horizontal line makes the following string:

```
101F*101F
1D21 1D21
2121 2121 
2820 2820     
2C20 2C20
3120 3120
3921 3921
3F21 3F21
4521 4521
4A21 4A21
5122 5122
5822 5822
6121 6121
6421 6421
6721 6721
6A20 6A20
6C20 6C20
6F20 6F20
7220 7220
7520 7520
7720 7720
7920 7920
7D20 7D20
8020 8020
8120 8120
8320 8320
861F 861F
871F 871F
891F 891F
8A1F 8A1F
8D1F 8D1F
8F1F 8F1F
931F 931F
961F 961F
971F 971F
9A1F 9A1F
9C1F 9C1F
9D1E 9D1E
A11E A11E
A31E A31E
A51D A51D
A71D A71D
A91D A91D
AA1C AA1C
AB1C AB1C
AD1C AD1C
AE1C AE1C
B01C B01C
B11B B11B
B21B B21B
B41B B41B
B51A B51A
B61A B61A
B81A B81A
B919 B919
BB19 BB19
BC19 BC19
BD19 BD19
BE19 BE19
BF19 BF19
C019 C019
C11A C11A
C31A C31A
C41A C41A
C51A C51A
C61B C61B
C71B C71B
C81C C81C
C81C
```

[image: Single Line]

So this is what makes the PictureBox Signature to a string:

```
'signature
Public gSigPoints() As Long
Public gSigLines() As Long

Public gSigPointCount As Long
Public gSigLinesCount As Long

Public Function PackBMP() As String

Dim tmpStr1 As String
Dim tmpStr2 As String
Dim tmpStr3 As String
Dim tmpStr4 As String
Dim tmp As Long

    gJob_Signature = ""

    For tmp = 1 To gSigPointCount

        tmpStr1 = CStr(Hex(gSigPoints(1, tmp)))
        tmpStr2 = CStr(Hex(gSigPoints(2, tmp)))

        If Len(tmpStr1) = 2 And Len(tmpStr2) = 2 Then
          gJob_Signature = gJob_Signature & tmpStr1 & tmpStr2 '& ";" & ";"
        Else
          If Len(tmpStr1) = 1 Then tmpStr1 = "0" & tmpStr1
          If Len(tmpStr2) = 1 Then tmpStr2 = "0" & tmpStr2
          If Len(tmpStr1) = 2 And Len(tmpStr2) = 2 Then
            gJob_Signature = gJob_Signature & tmpStr1 & tmpStr2  '& ";"& ";"
          End If
        End If


    Next 'tmp

    gJob_Signature = gJob_Signature & "*"

    For tmp = 1 To gSigLinesCount

        tmpStr1 = CStr(Hex(gSigLines(1, tmp)))
        tmpStr2 = CStr(Hex(gSigLines(2, tmp)))
        tmpStr3 = CStr(Hex(gSigLines(3, tmp)))
        tmpStr4 = CStr(Hex(gSigLines(4, tmp)))

        If Len(tmpStr1) = 2 And Len(tmpStr2) = 2 And Len(tmpStr3) = 2 And Len(tmpStr4) = 2 Then
          gJob_Signature = gJob_Signature & tmpStr1 & tmpStr2 & tmpStr3 & tmpStr4  '& ";"
        Else
          If Len(tmpStr1) = 1 Then tmpStr1 = "0" & tmpStr1
          If Len(tmpStr2) = 1 Then tmpStr2 = "0" & tmpStr2
          If Len(tmpStr3) = 1 Then tmpStr3 = "0" & tmpStr3
          If Len(tmpStr4) = 1 Then tmpStr4 = "0" & tmpStr4

          If Len(tmpStr1) = 2 And Len(tmpStr2) = 2 And Len(tmpStr3) = 2 And Len(tmpStr4) = 2 Then
            gJob_Signature = gJob_Signature & tmpStr1 & tmpStr2 & tmpStr3 & tmpStr4   '& ";"
          End If
        End If

    Next 'tmp

End Function


Public Sub DrawBMP(ByRef pic As PictureBox)
Dim x As Long

  pic.Cls
  For x = 1 To gSigPointCount
    Call pic.DrawPoint(gSigPoints(1, x), gSigPoints(2, x))
  Next x

  For x = 1 To gSigLinesCount
    Call pic.DrawLine(gSigLines(1, x), gSigLines(2, x), gSigLines(3, x), gSigLines(4, x), 0)
  Next x
  pic.Refresh

End Sub


Public Sub AddPoint(x As Long, Y As Long)

  gSigPointCount = gSigPointCount + 1
  ReDim Preserve gSigPoints(2, gSigPointCount)
  gSigPoints(1, gSigPointCount) = x
  gSigPoints(2, gSigPointCount) = Y

End Sub



Public Sub AddLine(x As Long, Y As Long, x1 As Long, y1 As Long)

  gSigLinesCount = gSigLinesCount + 1
  ReDim Preserve gSigLines(4, gSigLinesCount)
  gSigLines(1, gSigLinesCount) = x
  gSigLines(2, gSigLinesCount) = Y
  gSigLines(3, gSigLinesCount) = x1
  gSigLines(4, gSigLinesCount) = y1

End Sub

'********signature
Private miX As Double
Private miY As Double
Private isup As Boolean
'*********end of signature

'@@ singnatures
Private Sub picDraw_MouseDown(Button As Long, Shift As Long, x As Double, Y As Double)

    picDraw.DrawPoint x, Y, 0
    picDraw.Refresh
    Call AddPoint(x, Y)
    miX = x
    miY = Y
    isup = False

End Sub



Private Sub picDraw_MouseMove(Button As Long, Shift As Long, x As Double, Y As Double)

  If isup Then
    miX = x
    miY = Y
    isup = False
  Else

    If Button = 1 Then

      picDraw.DrawLine miX, miY, x, Y, 0
      picDraw.Refresh
      Call AddLine(miX, miY, x, Y)
      miX = x
      miY = Y
    End If

  End If

End Sub



Private Sub picDraw_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Double, ByVal Y As Double)
  isup = True
End Sub
```

This is all I can see regarding the signature picture box.

Comment: Added a Bitmap file and its related string

Comment: No its not encrypted

Comment: If you look at the image I posted this is a signature I.e a person making a scribble on the mobile device. E.g signing for a parcel delivery. Hope this helps

Comment: The size of the string varies the resolution should be the same.

Comment: The basic code is not my issue as I need to make this in C# my issue is I have not worked with images much.

Comment: I basically need to convert the image to that type of string and it's not a conventional one as far as I can see.

Comment: How would I get the word size you mention i.e 3711 in my image

Comment: I have another example image and it's string if it helps.

Comment: There are no digits I can see it is a scribble. What do you mean by number of digits?

Comment: If I may add the fuller the area in the picture box the longer the string.

Comment: the image size will always be the same i.e. 206 x 64 I don't have any control over this. I will However, try a couple of signatures, one with a single dot and one with a single line and see what the string looks like. I only have access to the code that deals with the conversion of the string to an image but don't unfortunately have access to the pocket pc project as this was developed by a contractor. Will post me results here

Comment: I believe that the current solution is using mouse down and up events and records these as Hex strings but its all in VB.

Comment: I cannot do a straight line as the mobile device uses a stylus so it is hand drawn. A single dot is not possible as it complains there is no signature. The person that originally created the code cannot be reached. But I did manage to get the VB code that creates the string although I can't make anything out of it as I am not good with Graphics. If it helps I can post the VB code that does the signature strings maybe you can have a glance.

Comment: Posted all the code that deals with the creation of the string, its crazy.

Comment: Its Ok this is only one of many items to do in the project so I have time :)

Comment: I cleared the old comments of mine (you should do the same for unimportant comments) Added answer with the signature format (tested and working for signatures you provided). You where right it is the mouse movement encoded to string (but in a silly way wasting about 50% space making it very confusing ... may be by design).

Comment: So now the question is what is your input image ... If you sampling it on your self then just do it in a manner I described in my answer. If it is vector then you should also have no problems. But if it is a pure raster image then you need to vectorize it first and that may cause problems (because you lost information about how the image was drawed so mis matches may occur) Also you should retag the VB to the target language you want to use now ...

Comment: My input image is a jpeg file with a signature. I don't know who coded it or why it was done that way. All I have are images. One question I have is how bad will these mismatches be ? Are they very significant or will it result in a completely different image or will there just be bits missing from the signature ? I will look into vectorizing the images and see what   happens.

Comment: I overlooked this comment (you forgot to add `@ Spektre` so I was not notified. the image will look the same. but if the person who signs the image will sign on the device with the VB code of yours then the resulting strings will be completely different. So there is very high probability that the classification will not match the signs as the same (unless it uses some highly sophisticated polygon comparisons or compare rasterised images instead which is in digital signatures very doubtfull for security reasons)

Comment: @Spektre Thank you very much you have been very helpful I am going to work out how to vectorise the image using my bmp file and hopefully get it done. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the encoding out from the code you posted (had to port it to C++ though) so the encoding:

1. **string starts with list of points**

   Each point is present as 4-digit hex number. First 2 hex digits are `x` coordinate and the second 2 digits are `y` coordinate of point. (probably marking each mouse down event so it holds the info on how many continuous draws the image was drawn)
2. **then separator `*` follows**
3. **after that list of lines is present**

   Each line contains 2 points so total of 8-digits hex number per line. The sequence is `x0,y0,x1,y1` 2-digit hex number per coordinate. If the string contains only 4-digit hex number (the end) it marks the end of signature string.

**So when you want to make own signature code then:**

1. **clear list of points and list of lines**
2. **on mouse down (left button click on or pen hit) event**

   Add current mouse/pen position to the point list and as a start point to line list
3. **on mouse/pen move event**

   First find out if the mouse button is still clicked or pen still hitting the pad. If not ignore this event. If yes then add current mouse position to line list twice (that is why they are duplicated the first ends current line and the second starts new line)
4. **on mouse/pen up event**

   close the actual line so add current mouse position to line list once
5. **before exporting**

   duplicate last point in lines list to mark end of string

That is all. If you need to convert already drawed image (raster) then you may have problems with comparison because is very unlikely you vectorize the image the same way as the author signs it. Resulting in miss-match of the same images. Also the tripled last point is most likely because of wrong encoding of mouse/pen up event adding the same point inside on `mouse move` and on `mouse up` events at once

The images encoded this way are limited to 256x256 pixels.

**Here example of decoded image for your first signature string:**

[image: signature]

`signature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`

**here square example**

[image]

`signature="0808*080820082008202020200820082008080808";`

so when reordered:

```
0808  // point(8h,8h);
*     // separator
08 08 20 08 // line( 8h, 8h,20h, 8h)
20 08 20 20 // line(20h, 8h,20h,20h)
20 20 08 20 // line(20h,20h, 8h,20h)
08 20 08 08 // line( 8h,20h, 8h, 8h)
08 08       // not enough points -> end of string
```

**[Edit1] raster image to string conversion**

First you need to convert your image to vector form. There are many sophistikated approaches to polygonize raster image to vector form but they are usually using advanced things from math,image processing,structures etc... requiring extensive knowledge on the subject. As I assume you need this just to visualize something on the device so Instead I would use very simple conversion resulting in unreasonable big results (in comparison to the advanced approaches). If your device does not have too small limit on the string size then you should be fine otherwise you would need use something more advanced then this:

1. **clear your vector representation**

   list of points and list of lines
2. **loop through all horizontal lines of image**
3. **process each line**

   1. find first set pixel from current position `x0`
   2. find first unset pixel from current position `x1`
   3. if `x0,x1` found then

      - add point `(x0,y)`
      - add line `(x0,y,x1-1,y)`
4. after whole image processed convert vector form to string

   1. clear string
   2. add list of all points to string
   3. add separator `*` to string
   4. add list of all lines to string

This is how it looks like in C++:

```
// load input 2D BW (binary) image
backbuffer in;
in.bmp->LoadFromFile("in.bmp");
in.resize(in.bmp->Width,in.bmp->Height);

int x0,x1,x,y;
// clear signature vecor represenytation
gSigPoints.num=0;
gSigLines.num=0;
for (y=0;y<in.ys;y++)
 for (x=0;x<in.xs;)
    {
    for (;(x<in.xs)&&(!in.pyx[y][x]);x++); x0=x;    // find start of V-line
    for (;(x<in.xs)&&( in.pyx[y][x]);x++)  x1=x;    // find end of V-line
    if (x0<in.xs)                                   // add pnt,line to signature
        {
        gSigPoints.add(x0);
        gSigPoints.add(y );
        gSigLines.add(x0);
        gSigLines.add(y );
        gSigLines.add(x1);
        gSigLines.add(y );
        }
    }
// update string and screen
txt=PackBMP();
draw();
```

- where `in.xs,in.ys` is input image resolution
- `in.pyx[y][x]` is the image pixel access
- `txt` is the signature string
- `gSigPoints,gSigLines` are lists holding the signature points and lines
- these list have `.num` the number of items and `.add(a)` adds `a` to the end of the list

The pack/unpack ported from your VB code looks like this:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "list.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
List<DWORD> gSigPoints;
List<DWORD> gSigLines;
// some test examples:
//AnsiString txt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
//AnsiString txt="3711*371127152715103510351F2C1F2C312231223C1C3C1C3D203D20352D352D333233323D2E3D2E52225222671A671A6C196C196D1A6D1A6D1D6D1D69226922652665266428642864296429652965296E236E23781E781E8718871891179117961896189A199A199B1B9B1B9D1E9D1E9F209F20A021A021A021";
AnsiString txt="0808*08082008200820202020082008200808";
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString Hex(DWORD x,DWORD digits)
    {
    int i;
    char *tab="0123456789ABCDEF";
    AnsiString s="";
    if (digits>8) digits=8;
    s.SetLength(digits);
    for (i=digits;i>0;i--,x>>=4) s[i]=tab[x&15];
    return s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString PackBMP()
    {
    DWORD i;
    AnsiString sig="";
    // all points
    for (i=0;i+1<gSigPoints.num;)
        {
        sig+=Hex(gSigPoints[i],2); i++; // x
        sig+=Hex(gSigPoints[i],2); i++; // y
        }
    // separator
    sig+="*";
    // all lines
    for (i=0;i+3<gSigLines.num;i++)
        {
        sig+=Hex(gSigLines[i],2); i++;  // x0
        sig+=Hex(gSigLines[i],2); i++;  // y0
        sig+=Hex(gSigLines[i],2); i++;  // x1
        sig+=Hex(gSigLines[i],2); i++;  // y1
        }
    return sig;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void UnpackBMP(AnsiString &sig)
    {
    DWORD a,x,y;
    int i=1,l=sig.Length();
    // all points
    for(gSigPoints.num=0;(i+3<=l)&&(sig[i]!='*');)
        {
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10;        x =a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10; x<<=4; x|=a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10;        y =a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10; y<<=4; y|=a; i++;
        gSigPoints.add(x);
        gSigPoints.add(y);
        }
    // separator
    i++;
    // all lines
    for(gSigLines.num=0;i+7<=l;)
        {
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10;        x =a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10; x<<=4; x|=a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10;        y =a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10; y<<=4; y|=a; i++;
        gSigLines.add(x);
        gSigLines.add(y);
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10;        x =a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10; x<<=4; x|=a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10;        y =a; i++;
        a=sig[i]-'0'; if (a>9) a+='0'-'A'+10; y<<=4; y|=a; i++;
        gSigLines.add(x);
        gSigLines.add(y);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void DrawBMP(TCanvas *can)
    {
    DWORD i,x,y;
    // all points
    for (i=0;i+1<gSigPoints.num;)
        {
        x=gSigPoints[i]; i++;
        y=gSigPoints[i]; i++;
        can->Pixels[x][y]=can->Pen->Color;
        }
    // all lines
    for (i=0;i+3<gSigLines.num;)
        {
        x=gSigLines[i]; i++;
        y=gSigLines[i]; i++;
        can->MoveTo(x,y);
        x=gSigLines[i]; i++;
        y=gSigLines[i]; i++;
        can->LineTo(x,y);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void signature_on_mouse(backbuffer &scr)
    {
    DWORD x,y;
    // mouse left button last and actual
    bool q0=scr.sh0.Contains(ssLeft);
    bool q1=scr.sh1.Contains(ssLeft);
    bool _redraw=false;
    // actual mouse position
    x=scr.mx1;
    y=scr.my1;
    // on mouse down event
    if ((!q0)&&(q1))
        {
        gSigPoints.add(x); gSigLines.add(x);
        gSigPoints.add(y); gSigLines.add(y);
        _redraw=true;
        }
    // on mouse move event
    if ((q0)&&(q1))
        {
        gSigLines.add(x);
        gSigLines.add(y);
        gSigLines.add(x);
        gSigLines.add(y);
        _redraw=true;
        }
    // mouse mouse up event
    if ((q0)&&(!q1))
        {
        gSigLines.add(x);
        gSigLines.add(y);
        _redraw=true;
        txt=PackBMP();
        }
    // right mouse button clears signature
    if (scr.sh1.Contains(ssRight))
        {
        gSigPoints.num=0;
        gSigLines.num=0;
        _redraw=true;
        }
    if ((_redraw)&&(scr.win)) scr.win->Repaint();
    scr.rfs_mouse();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- where backbuffer is mine class to interface the window backbuffer image and mouse handler events.
- So just change `List<>,AnsiString,Backbuffer` to your platform style.

This can handle any raster binary image not just signatures:

[image: raster -> signature example]

But as you can see the size of signature string is ~ `13.9 KByte`

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer and it would be what I am looking for, however what I need to be able to do is to get a bitmap image and compile the string as I do not capture Mouse Events or anything because this process is backend only so I cannot do so. Is there anything you can think of that might get close. All I have are the images  .

Comment: yes you can scan for first set point ... scan the connected points to it adding as a line ... (removing from input bitmap when no more point near scann again until empty bitmap i sleft ... BUT THIS WAY YOU WILL GET DIFFERENT STRING THEN THE ONE OBTAINED BY DRAWING ....

Comment: Would you be able to advise how I could accomplish this ? I don't mind if the string is different as long as the image is close to the original. Apologies but my knowledge of Graphics is very poor so any help would be welcomed.

Comment: @user3262640 if you want just the image representation then yes ... when I would have the time/will will code something in C++  (may be tomorrow)

Comment: yes all I need is the image representation but in the format 3456*345627102710 etc....

Comment: @user3262640 added [edit1] also have you any constraints on the signature string? like max `length`,  max number of `ponts,lines` ?

Comment: there is only ever one point e.g. 7589*  and many lines after that.

Comment: @user3262640 no there are as many points as you have polylines in image. If you draw signature with 1 continuous move then you got 1 point. But if you got more moves then you got more points at least according to the source code you provided. If you have some kind of restrictions on the device/driver side let me know and also a sample of image to convert would be a great so the process can be adapted to the target images and not for generic ones.