# handwriting recognition code in android

Tags: android, image-processing

I am using canvas and taking  hand writing as input, I need to save that user entered writing into the text format.How to recognise user entered data and save in text format.

Comment: you have to convert image into text using ocr..

Comment: have a look at this http://www.abbyy.com/mobile-ocr/android-ocr/

Comment: You can process image and save text from it using following library:- https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two which is free.

Comment: i didn't get that explaination of above link@ELITE

Comment: I am using eclipse@AdarshYadav

Comment: **if this is a signature string then the txt form is not obtained via OCR !!!** Instead it is representation of the signature in kind of vector/RLE form in ASCII format. see [Convert Signature Bitmap to Signature String](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33171669/2521214). So you should clear this out if this is signature string or any image with text on it and want to OCR it. (edit your question and add example)

Comment: Not like in above link,if user signatures their name i want to store their name from signature(in alphabet's)@Spektre