# Mouse Interfacing In Turbo C++

Tags: mouse, dos, turbo-c++

I am trying to add interactive mouse interfacing to my program but I am not able to understand the need for `delay()` in it.

Here's the code:

```
do
{
    getmousepos(&button,&x,&y);
    if(button==1)
    {
        delay(500);
        xx[i] = x;
        yy[i] = y;
        i++;
    }
}while(!kbhit());
```

Not sure what `delay()` does here. Because if the button is pressed, the co-ordinates will get allocated to their respective arrays anyway. Then what is the need to add a delay?

The program with `delay()` gives proper output.
But if I remove it, nothing gets printed on screen.
What's so important about `delay()` in this case?

Comment: Is this question really about MS-DOS, the OS from the 80's, or is it about the Windows command prompt?

Comment: Sparky's answer covers your question however I would add a value to the buffer only on change so `abs(xx-x[i-1])+abs(yy-y[i-1])>threshold` that could get rid of the `delay` and improve the sensitivity and and overall feeling of mouse handling. Also mouse events usually should handle states like `Button_press, Button_hold, Button_release` and or `click, double-click,triple-click`  so I would expect to store last state of button and have some functionality (reset buffer, filling buffer, executing buffer) on each of the first events ...

Comment: For more info see [Convert Signature Bitmap to Signature String (very strange one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33171669/2521214) and look for `q0,q1` usage in the code of mine inside function `void signature_on_mouse(backbuffer &scr)` it does almost the same as your code ... its vritten in Borland/VCL/C++ fow Windows so the mouse API is different but the event code is almost the same as yours should be looking. However that one does not have the thresholding (as unlike your API that is already covered by the mouse API in that case). +1 for trying understand instead of just copy paste code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turbo C++ ... that takes me back.  Here is what I am expecting is happening and why that `delay()` is needed.

What you have here is a polling loop. Without the `delay()`, you are going to flood your *xx[]* and *yy[]* buffers when *button* is 1, and probably overflow them too. Remember, the computer can execute that loop a great many times while you have that mouse button pressed. The `delay()` evens that out somewhat.